# changing eclipse colors but don't know what this part of the screen is even called

Tags: eclipse, colors, color-scheme

Having tried and failed to convert my eclipse to a fully white on black display I tried to revert to black on white...and now have only one area remaining in the old mode.  The problem is I don't even know what this part of the screen is called, so I can't figure out where in the 18 places eclipse sets colors to go to fix it.

Its the area on the left of the Java editor where you see + or - for expanding / collapsing sections of text.  How do I set the background color of this area?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Plug-in Spy can help you here. Try Alt+Shift+F1. It shows details about the view you point your mouse at.